# searching for element in 4d array with specific properties

Tags: algorithm

I have a 4D array in which values are monotonic. How to search efficiently for a value.

Comment: Either way you are in at least O(N^3) complexity. Implement a tivial search and see if it has reasonable run time. If not, even if you improve the algorithm by a factor of 2, 3, 5 - it will not be fast enough.

Comment: By trivial I mean O(N^3 log N), which has brute for 3 diemensions and binary search for the last one. It should be very quick to implement. I think that O(N^3) complexity can be achieved (since it's possible to get O(N+M) for N^2) though I can't think of an algorithm that would do that.

Comment: How large is **N**? If it is small enough, perhaps you could use a hashtable of (value, locations).

Comment: If you only need to find a scalar value, what's the point of storing it in a sorted 4D matrix rather than a 1D sorted vector? A matrix can contain more than one of the same value, which seems to ruin the point of finding any one particular value.

Comment: @AndrewMorton: N is in the range of 100 to 10000

Comment: @BonzaiThePenguin: to state my question in a simple way, i said sorted matrix, it is infact a 4d grid with each point being f(x,y,z,w) and I dont have the function value in advance unless I evaluate it at any point. But one thing I know is the function value is monotonically non-decreasing along each dimension. That is why I want to minimize the number of comparisons meaning number of function calls.

Answer (score 1):

If N is no more than 10,000, then don't see why you can't use an unordered_set.  Then do a single lookup.  If there can be duplicate values for each dimension, then you would need to keep track of that somehow.  But, I don't know of any code that implements an unordered_set for C.  So, you would probably have to use C++ for that.

If you can't use an unordered_set, then since the data is in sorted order for each dimension, you could also use a binary search for each dimension.  That would mean looking up no more than 15 values for each dimension on average - assuming the total number of elements in each dimension is less than 16K.  15 lookups * 4 dimensions = 60 lookups.  Is that too slow?

One other improvement might be to create one large sorted and unique array from the 4 dimensions and search that one instead.  That would yield a total of about 17 lookups (assuming <= 64K elements) .vs. 60, which is 3.5+ times faster.  However, it would also depend on how often values are added or removed from the dimensions to determine whether it would really be faster or not - since you would have to add and remove them from the single table as well.  Plus, don't forget to use a table to keep track of duplicate values - if applicable.

If the values are relatively small integers - say a billion or less, then you might be able to use a bitmapping scheme.  The bitmapping scheme would be faster than using an unordered_set for each dimension.  An array of bytes can be used as the bitmap.  A value set in the bitmap means that the value is present.  For example, if the value is zero, then bit zero would be set.  If the value is 3, then bit 2 would be set.  If the value is 5, then bit 4 would be set, etc.  So, 100MB would need to be used to map all the values for 1 billion (2 ^ 30).  If duplicate values can exist in each dimension, then you would need to keep track of that so that when a value is removed from a dimension - it is not removed from the bitmap unless it does not exist in any other dimensions.  If your values are floating point numbers, then you could translate them to ints if the total number of significant digits is <= 9.  If the values are strings or structs, then a bitmapping scheme might still work if you could figure out a way to translate it to a unique integer.